# Using category feeds for Yahoo Pipes

Tags: drupal, rss, yahoo-pipes

I am using Yahoo Pipes API to create an application where i am picking up feeds from different websites. 
These feeds initially were the main rss feed of the blog. However, i need to take only those feeds which are a part of category.

So suppose there is a site mysitename.com with rss feeds at http://www.mysitename.ccom/rss.xml
This site has categories like

```
Nation/World    
sports
politics
LocaL   
health  
specials    
spotlight   
weather
```

Now i wish to get the RSS for these particular tags only.

First i was looking for some way to use Yahoo Pipe API filter to get the feeds with only these tags/categories, but yahoo pipes filter only support filtering with authorname, title, content but not tags or categories.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to filter these feeds in Yahoo Pipes API using some other operator?
2. Also, if this is not possible, i may wish to simply add urls like mysitename.com/tag1 but i could not find feeds here in this CMS (Drupal) for a particular tag. I would like to know how that can be grabbed.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally sites provide a seperate feed for each category, CNN & the BBC being good examples of this. So there is seldom a need for complex filtering. Sounds like you are trying to UN-mash somebody elses RSS mashup, sure it could be done but it would be easier to find out where it is getting its source data from.

**Yahoo Pipes Tip#4** # Since the V2 revision of Yahoo Pipes some options have been removed from the drop down selectors in the GUI but still exist in the inner workings of the backend. In addition to *item.authorname*, *item.title*, *item.description* etc selectors you can type in **item.content** by hand to perform an action such as filter or regex on all the data not just a part between  specicfied tags.